# Why does my HTML not change when I push a new value into an array?

Tags: angularjs

In my HTML I have:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in test.user">
..
</div>
```

In my code I get a new record and add this to an array:

```
 test.addTest = function(selectedRow) {
        $http({
            url: '/api/Test/Post/' + selectedRow,
            method: "POST"
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            test.user.push(data);
        });

    }
```

But the display doesn't show any change.  Can someone give me some advice as to why this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are updating your array outside the digest cycle. Try calling `scope.$apply` (please see the "life cycle" sections in [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

```
test.addTest = function(selectedRow) {
    $http({
        url: '/api/Test/Post/' + selectedRow,
        method: "POST"
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        scope.$apply(function () { test.user.push(data) };
    });

}
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me a message "$digest already in progress"

Comment: I think it may be that sometimes the HTTP takes longer than other times. Is there a way I could do the $apply only if it is not already in a digest cycle?

Comment: is `success` handler called at all when you expect the data to change?

Comment: also, I would think that `test` should be defined on `scope` so I would expect to see `scope.test.user.push()` call in the `success` handler.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the full code but here is a sample fiddle similar to what you are doing without the POST: http://jsfiddle.net/VFBTy/6/

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="row in test.user">
        {{ row }}
    </div>

    <input type="text" ng-model="test.input" />
    <button type="button" ng-click="test.addTest(test.input)">Add</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.test = {
        user: [ 'One', 'Two' ],
        addTest: function (data) {
            if($scope.test.user.indexOf(data) === -1) {
                $scope.test.user.push(data);
            } else {
                alert('cannot add dupes');   
            }
        },
        input: ''
    };

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define `test.user` under `$scope` or the variable will not be visible to the HTML.

Assuming that function `addTest()` is inside your controller and your controller is already injected with `$scope`, your code becomes

```
// inside controller code

// initialize $scope.test.user as an empty array
// before appending any user(s) into it
$scope.test.user = [];

$scope.test.addTest = function(selectedRow) {
    $http({
        url: '/api/Test/Post/' + selectedRow,
        method: "POST"
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.test.user.push(data);
    });
}
```